# Is it semantically relevant whether <sup> is placed inside or outside of <label>?

Tags: html

We are designing some applications and we are putting the `<sup>` element outside of the `<label>` element. For example:

```
<label ....>Email</label><sup>*</sup>
```

But we've had some developers who say it's semantically wrong to put `<label>` outside of `<sup>`. They argue that we should keep it inside of the `<label>` element, like so:

```
<label ....>Email <sup>*</sup></label>
```

Is this mentioned anywhere in the W3C specifications? Which way is semantically more correct?

Comment: Depends on what you want the * to mean, no?

Comment: @ScottHunter * means required and validation there.

Comment: The use of the sup element is not at all appropriate here.

Comment: @BoltClock any reasons?

Comment: @user960567: Think about why you're using a sup element in the first place. Is it simply to give the asterisk its own element? If so, use a span, or a pseudo-element, instead. Is it simply to force the asterisk to be superscript regardless of the typeface? Then you're using the sup for presentational purposes, which is a no-no; use a span with CSS instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The superscript formatting is irrelevant.

The significance is the message. "This is required" is part of the label so should be inside the label element.

`<sup>` ends up inside the label as a side effect of putting the content there.

Comment: Means putting `<sup>` inside or outside label is not semantically wrong?

Comment: Interestingly, the spec never accounts for this, neither in the forms section, nor in *Common idioms without dedicated elements*. It does not even suggest if the asterisk should be inserted with CSS instead - however, asterisks notably never appear in any of the examples containing labels and required fields.

Comment: Putting `*` outside the label is semantically wrong. Since it is the `*` you are superscript, putting `<sup>` outside creates an error in your described semantics as a side effect.

Comment: @BoltClock — The issues surrounding using `*` to mean "required" are a whole other story. :(

Comment: `creates an error in your described semantics as a side effect.` can you explain more?

Comment: If you move `<sup>` ouside the label then you move `*` outside the label, `*` is part of the information labelling the input, not putting `*` in a label element is wrong. Not that that is anything I haven't said already, but there is nothing more to say than that.